# Jboss AS 7 with CAS authentication and database authorizing

Tags: authentication, jboss, authorization, java-ee-6, cas

I would like to use CAS to make authentication and database to manage roles and permissions with JEE7 on JBoss wildfly, does it support this kind of realm ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CAS provide a filter for JBoss integration, it hide the boilerplate related to CAS protocol
Your principal is injected, you can retrieve it and then get its roles and permissions from the database